# Switching to Xcode 8.2.1 causes BRCloudDocsErrorDomain

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

When I switched from Xcode 7.3.1 to Xcode 8.2.1 I get the following error when I try to save (via Cmd+s) the first time.

> [ERROR] Failed getting container for URL: file:///Users/bob/Desktop/,
>   error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=12 "App library not
>   found: 'com.apple.Desktop'" UserInfo={NSDescription=App library not
>   found: 'com.apple.Desktop'}

When I tried to disable iCloud Drive from System Preferences.. I instead get the following error.

> [ERROR] Failed getting container for URL: file:///Users/bob/Desktop/,
>   error: Error Domain=BRCloudDocsErrorDomain Code=2 "Logged out - iCloud
>   Drive is not configured" UserInfo={NSDescription=Logged out - iCloud
>   Drive is not configured}

I am creating a MacOS app and I do not need to use Cloud, but it seems that the cloud is somehow involved when saving a document. What is the problem here and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem and I solved it by switching on Sandbox and by selecting which folders I wanted to use in my project parameters.

Hope that this help you

[image]

Comment: For some reason my xcode doesn't have a capabilities option. I only have; General, Resource Tags, Build Settings, Build Phases and Build Rules.